# Constructing a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Constructing a sequence of functions $(f_m)$ satisfying all following conditions
$\sup_m \int_1^m f_m(s)ds < \infty$ and $\lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \int_1^m dt \int_1^t \dfrac{f_m(s)}{s}ds = \infty$ and supp$f_m \subset (1, m)$ and $f_m > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Cauchy's formula for repeated integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) $$\int_1^m \int_1^t \frac{f_m(s)}{s} ds dt=\int_1^m (m-t) \frac{f_m(t)}{t} dt. $$
In light of this I would define $$f_m(t)=e^{-t} \chi_{(1,m)}=\begin{cases} e^{-t} & 1<t<m \\0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}.$$

EDIT:

More specifically,

- $\int_1^m f_m (t) \leq \int_1^\infty f_m(t) \leq \int_1^\infty e^{-t} dt=e^{-1}$. Thus $\sup_m \int_1^m f_m \leq e^{-1} < \infty$
- $\int_1^m \frac{m-t}{t} f_m(t) dt \geq \int_1^2 \frac{m-t}{t} e^{-t} dt$, which tends to $\infty$ as $m \to \infty$.
- Well, $\text{supp} f_m$ actually is $(1,m]$, so you should take the sequence $( f_{m-1} )$.

Comment: Can you prove it? I think It is not easy.